# I want to call the change event within the click event in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling

My goal is to detect the cancel buton click while uploading a file. I am trying to achieve this by invoking the click event. Then after the event is triggered, it will detect the change event. If the change event triggers, it will upload the document else if the cancel button is clicked(means the change event did not trigger) then it will throw an error.

```
<input type="file" formControlName="receipt" (click)="fileDeetect($event)" (change)="uploadReceipt($any($event.target).files)"
                  class="positionabsolute" style="opacity: 0; width: 0; height: 0" id="validatedCustomFile" required />
```

I tried to achieve it by using the angular form validator `markAsTouched()`. But it did not work as it will work once the file is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with javascript and typescript combination. I don't know exactly how your code looks, including the entire HTML and TypeScript. But I will try to create an example based on what I gather from the input.

Create in typescript new property

```
cancelClicked = false;
```

In html add `#fileInput` as template variable

```
<input type="file" formControlName="receipt" #fileInput
       (click)="fileDetect($event)" (change)="uploadReceipt($event.target.files)"
       class="positionabsolute" style="opacity: 0; width: 0; height: 0" id="validatedCustomFile" required />
```

fileDetect mehtod dunno how it looks like, but maybe somehting like this

```
fileDetect(event: Event) {
  // Check if the file input value is empty, indicating the cancel button was clicked
  this.cancelClicked = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value === '';
}
```

And lastly

```
uploadReceipt(files: FileList) {
  if (this.cancelClicked) {
    // Throw an error or handle the cancel button click event
    console.log('Cancel button clicked');
    return;
  }

  // Proceed with uploading the file
  // ...
}
```

Now, when the cancel button is clicked, the fileDetect method will set the cancelClicked property to true. In the uploadReceipt method, you can check the value of cancelClicked and do what you need.